# What is the expression for the sum of this series?

Tags: power-series

What is the sum of the series $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n+2}}{n(n+2)}$$ in terms of $x$, where $-1 \le x \le 1$?

I can clean it up by differentiating:$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n+1}}n$$but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: lol, my anterior comment was terrible wrong, sorry :p. If you differentiate again you get something easy to compute. Because $f''$ is uniformly convergent for $x\in(-1,1)$ then you can compute from here $f$. Pull out an $x$ in $f'$ and differentiate the series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n+1}}n=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}n:=xg(x)\\
g'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {x^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n}=\frac 1{1-x},\;|x|<1$$
Can you continue from there?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. You can proceed with the following standard [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n}}n=-\ln(1-x),\quad |x|<1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Try rewriting the series as: $$f(x)= \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n+2}\cdot\frac{1}{n(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n+2}\left(\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$$